# md-on-select called on every md-tab during destroy

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

We are using angular-material's md-tabs to display information to the user.
Up until now we used an on-demand approach by adding
`ng-click=vm.getForExampleDataForTab1()`,
`ng-click=vm.getForExampleDataForTab2()`
and so on for each md-tab. But this solution has a problem that the first tab is displayed with no data because it doesn't get clicked by the user. So we switched to `md-on-select` instead. And that did the trick, the first tab was getting data and all was fine. Apparently. We then discovered in Chrome's Dev tools that when moving to another page in the app, all the other tabs that were not selected (the user didn't click on them to view the data) were called.
Did anyone encounter such a behaviour? It only happens when we used `md-on-select`, not `ng-click` on the tabs.

Thanks a lot,
ashilon